# Trouble installing leiningen-win-installer 1.0 on Windows 10 behind firewall

Tags: clojure

I'm having trouble installing and configuring Leiningen on a Windows 10 work computer. I'm assuming that my company's firewall prevents the GitHub security certificate from authenticating.

The error I'm getting is:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The request
>   was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." At line:1
>   char:145
>   + ... che]::DefaultNetworkCredentials; $client.DownloadFile($a, $f)} "https ...
>   +                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
>
> Failed to download
>   https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/download/2.8.1/leiningen-2.8.1-standalone.zip

It is possible that the download failed due to "powershell",
"curl" or "wget"'s inability to retrieve GitHub's security certificate.
The suggestions below do not check certificates, so use this only if
you understand the security implications of not doing so.

The PowerShell failed to download the latest Leiningen version.
Try to use "curl" or "wget" to download Leiningen by setting up
the HTTP_CLIENT environment variable with one of the following
values:

- set HTTP_CLIENT=wget --no-check-certificate -O
- set HTTP_CLIENT=curl -f -L -k -o

NOTE: Make sure to *not* add double quotes when setting the value
      of HTTP_CLIENT

Answer (score 5):

Github only supports TSL 1.2. By default PowerShell doesn't support this protocol.

To add TSL 1.2 support to every PowerShell session you need to edit your PowerShell profile: **Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1**.

Path to profile (Windows 10):

> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Add this line to profile:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

After you add this line, try again with "lein self-install". At least this worked for me, remember to add PATH Variable.

Quick tutorial on how to add PATH variable:

1. Open up File Explorer
2. Right-click on This PC
3. Select Properties
4. On the left hand side of the new window select Advanced System Settings
5. On the bottom of this screen select Environment Variables…
6. Find the PATH variable
7. Append `;C\Lein\;` (path to folder where is your `lein.bat`) to the existing PATH variable

If everything worked you should have similar answer:

[image: CMD working lein]

Comment: I did not have a profile under the path you specify under Users. 

I created one by following the steps here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx 

Then, I added the line you suggested to turn on TLS 1.2, worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

If you have `curl` installed use the command it give you there:

```
set HTTP_CLIENT=curl -f -L -k -o
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The trick is to use `cmd` when executing this line. When in Powershell, type `cmd` to use this line. Then type `powershell` to go back again. Then `lein self-install` or whatever.

Comment: Would this solution be considered a security risk?